# Inserting date literals with time zone

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to pass in the dates in the formats I set with the `alter session` commands. Here's what I've tried thus far. Not understanding the invalid month error. I'm using 10g.

The database timezone is UTC

```
SELECT dbtimezone FROM DUAL;
UTC
```

I set the session time zone and date formats

```
alter session set time_zone = 'UTC';
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR';
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

The table I'm inserting the values in is below.

[image: table]

SQL code for a single record insert:

```
Insert into books_outsource_plan(os_cell_id, os_date, os_value, os_snapshot, os_created) 
values (1,'2013-03-08',3000,'2013-03-07 19:10:10 UTC','2013-03-08 19:15:54 UTC');
```

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Comment: Tried replacing the YYYY with RRRR that I saw in a similar question but it made no difference.

Comment: Try CASTING to to_date and then insert, give it a try...

Comment: The insert succeeds if I add `to_timestamp_tz` to the time stamp literals. Don't need to mess with the date literal apparently. However, when I query the table, timestamps don't match the literals I inserted. In particular, '2013-03-07 19:10:10 UTC' was converted to '07-MAR-13 02.10.10.0000000 PM'

Comment: I see the time shown is my local time which is odd because I thought the NLS setting would show it in UTC format.

Comment: The problem is with that only, thats why you were getting SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month error...

Comment: @Gopesh, put your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CASTING to **to_date** and then insert

LIKE

```
Insert into books_outsource_plan(os_cell_id, os_date, os_value, os_snapshot, os_created) 
values (1,to_date('2013-03-08'),3000,to_date('2013-03-07 19:10:10 UTC'),to_date('2013-03-08 19:15:54 UTC'));
```